# ajax call not working when deployed in live domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My ajax call is working on localhost but not when i upload the files in domain. Using ajax I am searching all jpg/png files in a folder called 'images' and showing them in my webpage. The code is -

```
<script>

//Use ajax to load all images (jpe?g|png|gif) from a folder to a page called Gallery
//images folder should be in the same folder as the file
      var folder = "../images/";
      $.ajax({
          url : folder,
          success: function (data) {
              $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                  if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {

// create 'img' element using JS and dynamically add image source and class
                      var imgSrc = document.createElement('img');
                      imgSrc.src= folder + val;
                      imgSrc.className = 'imageThumbnails';
                      $("#spanImage").append(imgSrc);
                  }
              });
          }
      });
</script>
```

Comment: You likely can't list the content of a folder on your remote server, for security reasons... If you go to the folder URL in your browser, does it allow you to view the content?

Comment: permission issue on your remote server. you need to adjust it I think

Comment: As @MacPrawn said, visit the live folder url in your browser and see whether the permissions are set. Most likely, they aren't.

Comment: You url is the problem.

Comment: try to add an error handler and see what is the problem there. you should always add error handle to you ajax calls anyway. so you could react on errors correctly

Comment: @MacPrawn - thanks! when i open the folder 'images' from my website directly like 'http://mywebsite.com/images' it initially gave 403 error. But then i created a dummy index.html file and i can access the folder from my browser (even though the page comes empty).
Permissions to that 'images' folder is set to 777 (I know this should not be, but i am just trying to run the website one time. I will modify the permissions later).

Comment: @PrahladYeri - thanks! i can access the live folder once i create a dummy index.html file. But still the ajax call is not working

Comment: @Roljhon - thanks.  Permissions to that 'images' folder is set to 777 (I know this should not be, but i am just trying to run the website one time. I will modify the permissions later).

Comment: @SpYk3HH - thanks.. can you please tell me what needs to be changed here to make it work?

Comment: You can use `beforeSend: function (xhr, opts)` and some console logging to figure out where your url is pointing to using that syntax, but my guess it, your live and dev have 2 diff folder layouts, thus the url having `../` is the issue

Answer (score 0):

please change

```
var folder = "../images/";
```

to

```
var folder = "images/";
```

hope this helps.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so as you saw when you tried accessing the folder directly in your browser, your web server does not allow this, which is common on web servers. Very few people actually want visitors to be able to see a list of all files in a folder, for security reasons.

The quick and dirty way to do this would be to allow listing files in that folder, through a htaccess file, using `Options +Indexes`, **but I strongly recommend you do not do that**

Instead, I would suggest you place a file inside your images folder called `index.php` and have *that* file build you a list of files placed alongside it, in the images folder. That way you have control over which files you show and which ones you don't. The index.php file can return a simple text output, one file name per line or something like that. Then your ajax call should work as it used to.

Hope this helps!